# jQuery UI droppable Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a form building tool. Everything was working just fine. I was able to drag my first icon and drop it on the main form body, just fine. When I do this, it appends a new div of class panel. I make panel droppable as well, however when I try to drop something on it nothing happens. If I hard code the div in it works fine, however when I append the div it does not. I'm having a lot of trouble figuring this out.

Here's my code:

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
    #toolbox
    {
        width: 100%;
        height: 200px;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        background-color: #666666;
        z-index: 2;
    }
    .icon
    {
        padding-top: 20px;
        padding-left: 20px;
        text-align: center;
        display: table-cell;
    }
    #formbuilder
    {
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 200px;
        left: 0px;
        bottom: 0px;
        padding-top: 5%;
        background-color: orange;
        opacity: 0.4;
        overflow: visible;
    }
    .panel
    {
        margin: 0 auto;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        height: 150px;
        width: 150px;
        background-color: blue;
        opacity: 0.4;
    }
</style>

</head>

<body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function formDropHandler(event, ui)
        {
            if(ui.draggable.hasClass("pan"))
            {
                var form = $("#formbuilder");
                form.append('<div class="panel ui-droppable"></div>');

                $(".panel").droppable({
                    drop: panelDropHandler
                });
            }
        }

        function panelDropHandler(event, ui)
        {
            if(ui.draggable.hasClass("tab")) alert("TRUE");
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {
            var icons = $('.icon');

            $('.icon').draggable({
                cursor: 'move',
                helper: 'clone',
                revert: true
            });

            $("#formbuilder").droppable({
                drop: formDropHandler
            });

            $(".panel").live('mouseover',function(){
                $(".panel").droppable({
                    drop: panelDropHandler
                });
            });
        });
    </script>

    <div id="toolbox">
        <div class="icon pan">Panel<br /><img src="panel.png" alt="PANEL.PNG" /></div>
        <div class="icon tab">Table<br /><img src="table.png" alt="TABLE.PNG" /></div>
    </div>

    <div id="formbuilder">
        <div class="panel"></div>
        <div class="panel"></div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Both drops are working now. The panel drops on the form builder and the table drops on the panels, (even the newly created ones). Just remember that the formbuilder is only the area that is colored in under the toolbar section. So the further you go down you won't be able to drop anything unless you scroll back up. But that's just a simple matter of CSS, change the `position:absolute` to `position:relative` and it should grow with the panels.

```
function formDropHandler(event, ui) {
    if (ui.draggable.hasClass("pan")) {
        var form = $("#formbuilder");
        form.append('<div class="panel ui-droppable"></div>');
    } else if (ui.draggable.hasClass("tab")){
       alert("TRUE");
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var icons = $('.icon');

    $('.icon').draggable({
        cursor: 'move',
        helper: 'clone',
        revert: true
    });

    $("#formbuilder").live('mouseover', function() {
        $("#formbuilder").droppable({
            drop: formDropHandler
        });
    });
    $(".panel").live('mouseover', function() {
        $(".panel").droppable({
            drop: formDropHandler
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried your code, it doesn't seem to work. What did I do wrong in my code? Thanks for trying, I appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: .panel is the class I'm giving. Oh, let me fix the first panel, thanks!

Alright, so I fixed it, and it still doesn't work. If I look at the panel I appended, it is of the class ui-droppable, so this is why I'm so damn confused. It's part of ui-droppable, however it doesn't do anything when I drop something on it.

Comment: The formbuilder remains completely functional and up to date with it's events. The panel that I add, displays that it is up to date, however when I drop something on it nothing happens, even though it is of the ui-droppable class. Do you think it has some conflict with the append() method? I'm totally lost here, but thanks for helping.

Comment: I tried this, didn't work. Did the exact same thing as the rest of them. This is what the panels looks like in the document:

    <div class="panel ui-droppable"></div>

I have no clue what the problem with this is. I get zero error's or warnings, it just doesn't work. I also haven't been able to get resizable to work. :(

Thanks for helping

Comment: Thanks. Ya I've omitted that. No matter how I add the ui-droppable class, it won't work. Maybe it's impossible to have a dynamically created element be droppable.

Comment: Okay, finally got it! [Check it out](http://jsfiddle.net/jtwebb/Ezhsb/). What you need is this: `$(".panel").live('mouseover',function(){
            $(".panel").droppable({
                drop: formDropHandler
            });
            });` And you don't add the class `ui-droppable`.

Comment: Thank you so much, i'm trying to implement it now.

Comment: Hmm, that didn't work either. This isn't any different is it? The only thing you changed was the drop: from panelDropHandler to formDropHandler. Am I missing something here? I'll update my current code in the main post. It only works in the first two that were initially coded in there.

Comment: That wasn't all that was done. I updated the original answer up top. And the link in my previous comment to jsfiddle will show you the code, you can even just copy and past it.

Comment: I saw the link and copied and pasted. Including all the html and css. Still doesn't work for me :( haha. Thanks for sticking with me this far, I'll try it again.

Comment: Still doesn't work for me :( Try pasting your entire file into pastebin or something, and I'll copy it straight out. Just to clarify, I want to be able to drop tables on top of the panels. So, tables should be able to be nested within the panels. You can't have panels within panels.

Comment: @Scriptonaut Check out the updated answer. It allows for the panels to be dropped on the form builder and the tables to be dropped on the panels. You're making me work for this one :)

Comment: IT WORKS! Thank you, I'm really confused why this works, and why the other didn't. Somehow only using one universal handler does the trick I guess. Anyways, am I supposed to set the thread as solved or something? This is my first post.

Comment: The reason is that once you appended the new div, it had know way of knowing that the droppable was supposed to be bound to it. That's why I added the live() function to both the form builder and the panels. The live() function binds not only the current elements, but also all those created in the future. So now those elements know that they are droppable. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Only those elements which are existing when you called .droppable() were made "dropables". Since you ran it once, at doc ready, then never again, any elements which are added to the page after-the-fact are just run-of-the-mill elements.

You will need to initialise each new addition. You can do this quickly by turning around your append statement.

```
var form = $("#formbuilder");
$('<div class="panel ui-droppable"></div>')
    .appendTo(form)
    .droppable({drop:panelDropHandler});
```

Comment: But I do run it again. If you run my program, and use the developer tool, the panel's I add are part of the class ui-droppable. See function formDropHandler. Inside I not only literally have it start out in the class ui-droppable, but I also use jquery to go through all .panel's and add it, just like at doc ready.

Comment: I tried your latest advice and still nothing. It claims that panel is of the class ui-droppable, but it doesn't behave like it. Thanks for trying.

Comment: I didn't change anything, because I'm trying to find something wrong with your code. It works fine at http://jsfiddle.net/dxNGb/ what's "not working" for you?

Comment: So, I want the program to let me drag a panel out on the formbuilder, and then append a panel to the formbuilder when I do this. This part works great. The second part I want is to be able to drag a table on the recently appended panel. This does not work. Table is draggable, and it claims that panel is droppable. However, when I drop a table on the panel nothing happens.